# ValueError: unconverted data remains on Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

**Data**  - Here's my data in a Pandas DataFrame

```
CallDateAndTimeStart
01/01/2010 00:26:28.003613 MST
01/01/2010 00:28:54.230713 MST
01/02/2008 14:12:11 MST
05/19/2010 09:12:32.080728 MST
```

**My attempt to change column dtype to datetime64[ns]**

```
df['CallDateAndTimeStart'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['CallDateAndTimeStart'],
    format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

**Error Message** - Without cleaning the data, I get the following error:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\tools.py", line 308, in _convert_listlike raise e
ValueError: unconverted data remains: .003613 MST
```

**Question**

How would I correct my dataframe column so that it can convert to a datetime type?  I posted my answer, but is there a better answer?  Thanks.

Comment: You can `exact=False`, if you don't need the rest of data, like microseconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code**

I apply a custom function on the DataFrame column (convert_time)

```
df['CallDateAndTimeStart'] = df['CallDateAndTimeStart'].apply(convert_time)

def convert_time(mytime):
""" Fix DateTime by removing details after . and timezones """

    # Remove on period and after
    try:
        mytime = str(mytime).split(".")[0]
    except ValueError:
        print "Not able to split ."

    # Remove Timeframe (E.g. MST)
    mytime = str(mytime).split(" ")[0] + " " + str(mytime).split(" ")[1]

return mytime

df['CallDateAndTimeStart'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['CallDateAndTimeStart'],
    format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

**Output**

```
CallDateAndTimeStart
2010-01-01 00:26:28
2010-01-01 00:28:54
2010-05-19 09:12:32
2008-01-02 14:12:11
2010-01-01 00:39:41
```

Answer (score 3):

You received an error since you didn't define the format of the microseconds and the timezone.

If all the rows were in the same format, the correct format will be:

```
df['CallDateAndTimeStart'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['CallDateAndTimeStart'],
format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f %Z')
```

Since not all the rows are in the same format, the best way is to let pandas infer the format without declaring it:

```
df['CallDateAndTimeStart'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['CallDateAndTimeStart'])
```

The output:

```
        CallDateAndTimeStart
0 2010-01-01 00:26:28.003613
1 2010-01-01 00:28:54.230713
2 2008-01-02 14:12:11.000000
3 2010-05-19 09:12:32.080728
```

Notice that in this solution the time zone is being ignored since MST is not recognized but you can convert the datetime object to the correct time zone with tz_convert.
Also, if you are not intrested in the microseconds, you can easily round it once it is a datetime object:

```
df['CallDateAndTimeStartRounded'] = df['CallDateAndTimeStart'].dt.floor('s')
```

The output:

```
        CallDateAndTimeStart CallDateAndTimeStartRounded
0 2010-01-01 00:26:28.003613         2010-01-01 00:26:28
1 2010-01-01 00:28:54.230713         2010-01-01 00:28:54
2 2008-01-02 14:12:11.000000         2008-01-02 14:12:11
3 2010-05-19 09:12:32.080728         2010-05-19 09:12:32
```

Answer (score 2):

I encounterd the same question and I used a same way like you to solve it.(apply a function to remove the unnecessary data)

I guess you could use the standard interface to avoid this issue:

```
>>> now = time.time() # get current time in second
>>> now_format = time.ctime(now) # get formatted time, like 'Thu May 21 17:43:46 2015'
```

and then use time.strptime() to get a standard time struct:

```
>>> standard_time_struct = time.strptime(now_format,"%a %B %d %X %Y")
```

you can get the final result like this:

```
>>> standard_time_struct
>>> time.struct_time(tm_year=2015, tm_mon=5, tm_mday=21, tm_hour=17, tm_min=49, tm_sec=10, tm_wday=3, tm_yday=141, tm_isdst=-1)
```